# Returned options are not seem by selector

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm writing a function in plain Javascript where I submit some values via AJAX and if it returns results. What is returned is a string with new options for a selector. I need to remove all options from a selector and replace them with the set that's returned.

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelector">
....
</select>
```

**JS**

```
(async () => {
    ....
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers,
        body
    });

    if (results.ok) {                                
        let myoptions = await results.text();
        var myselectr = document.querySelector("#mySelector");
        myselectr.innerHTML = "";                     
        myselectr.append(myoptions);
    }
})();
```

It seems to return options and I see them added in DOM but the selector does not seem to see them as options. The thing is I actually need to build the options using my PHP functionality. I think it is because I return it as text string. Not really sure.

What am I missing here?

Comment: When click on the selector to expand it looks like it has no options and when I inspect the source code in browser the options look grayed-out.

Answer (score 3):

[`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) inserts the [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)s as [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) nodes, causing HTML to be escaped. You should be assigning `myoptions` to the select's `innerHTML` instead:

```js
(async () => {
    ....
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers,
        body
    });

    if (results.ok) {                                
        let myoptions = await results.text();
        var myselectr = document.querySelector("#mySelector");
        myselectr.innerHTML = myoptions;                     

    }
})();
```

Comment: Bang - we have a winner! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

What is the return format after you made the request is it a array.. if its a array then append options manually using a for loop.

```
var myselectr = document.querySelector("#mySelector");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Text";
option.value = "myvalue";
myselectr.append(option);
```